Verify this proof by induction
I want to show the following

A connected graph with $n$ vertices is a tree if and only if it has $n-1$ edges.

Let $T$ be a tree. Denote the order of $T$ by $|T|$ and the size by $||T||$.
Proof. Suppose $T$ is a tree with $n$ vertices; we use induction on the order of $T$. If $n=1$ then the edge set of $T$ is empty. For the induction step suppose $n>1$, and suppose the claim holds for trees of order less than $n$. Let $n=k$ and observe that whenever $n=k+1$ there exist a leaf $v\in T$ such that $|T-v|=k$ and by our assumption $||T-v||=k-1$. As $v$ is a leaf, adding such to $T$ increases both order and size by one. By the induction hypothesis, a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges must be a tree.
Is this proof correct? I feel like I should work on the wording as well, but I want to make sure there are no logical flaws.

I find it difficult to follow how "both implications" in the "if and only if" follows from this proof.

The biggest problem: if you let $T$ be a tree with $n$ vertices and induct on $n$, then what you'll be proving is a statement "For all trees $T$, ...", and that can't possibly be the if-and-only-if statement you want.
The claim to be proved can be separated into two parts:

If $T$ is a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $T$ is a tree, then $T$ has $n-1$ edges. (All trees are connected, so effectively this part of the claim is simply, "If $T$ is an $n$-vertex tree, then $T$ has $n-1$ edges.")
If $T$ is a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $T$ has $n-1$ edges, then $T$ is a tree. (The most common definition of a tree is "an acyclic, connected graph", so we just need to prove that $T$ is acyclic.)

The current proof can only be a proof of part 1.

To prove part 1, the strategy of removing a leaf can definitely be used. However, two justifications are missing:
First, you must prove that $T$ has a leaf $v$. (Maybe you've already shown that every tree on $2$ or more vertex has a leaf, in class or in a previous exercise, so then you can simply cite that fact.)
Second, in order to apply the induction hypothesis to $T-v$, you must prove that $T-v$ is a tree. (It is clear that $T-v$ is acyclic; to prove that $T-v$ is connected, argue that no path in $T$ can enter and leave $v$.)

Proving part 2 of the claim can be done very similarly, but there are a few minor changes:

The assumption on $T$ is that it is a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges.

Once again, we must prove that $T$ has a leaf, but this time we are showing it with different assumptions. (The degree sum formula may be useful here.)

To apply the induction hypothesis to $T-v$, we must still show that $T-v$ is connected, but that part is the same as before.

Finally, to use the induction hypothesis, we need to show that if $T-v$ is acyclic, then $T$ is also acyclic (and therefore a tree).


Personally, I would not use induction for either part of this claim; I would start with the lemmas that a connected $n$-vertex graph must contain at least $n-1$ edges, and that an acyclic $n$-vertex graph can contain at most $n-1$ edges (in other words, every $n$-vertex graph with at least $n$ edges contains a cycle).
